# Separator between content and bottom navigation view (material) like PlayStore

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

The new play store bottom navigation bar looks like [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-play-store-material-theme-redesign/).
As you can see there is a separator between the bottom navigation bar and the main content.
How do I achieve this separator?
I am using a material BottomNavigationView.

My current XML looks like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/tab_item"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/tab_item"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />
```

Comment: Please post some code what you tried

Comment: are you asking how to draw a line?

Comment: No, obviously I could just use a custom view and draw a line but I thought there might be an easier way, maybe the play store is not using the material BottomNavigationView.

Comment: which seperarator ??

Comment: The separator between the bottom navigation bar and the main content frame. You can see that on the screenshots when you click on the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out how the play store is doing it.
There exists a material component called "Divider".

I just added it as a child view of the BottomNavigationView and it looks exactely the same as on the play store.

Here's the new code of the child view:

```
<com.google.android.material.divider.MaterialDivider
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: so just drawing a line after all